# What is the Cancellation fee for UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

What are the charges of cancelling the UK visa application?
I haven't done the biometrics yet in fact not even booked the appointment, just submitted the application on gov.uk website and done the payment. So -

1. Will I get a full refund or there is some cancellation fees if I cancel the visa application?
2. Can I reapply immediately after cancellation?

This is for standard Visitor Visa.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're looking to cancel the application and reapply immediately? Is there an error on your application you need to correct?

Answer (score 7):

The [gov.uk site](https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa) has a whole page about this, the summary at the top states:

If you applied **outside the UK** [contact UKIV](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) to find out how to cancel your application

> You can only get your fee refunded if your application hasn’t been
>   processed yet.

If you applied **within the UK** 
You can cancel via an [online form](https://eforms.homeoffice.gov.uk/outreach/Return_of_Documents.ofml), but you will not be refunded.

> You won’t get your fee refunded if you cancel an application that you
>   made in the UK.

Comment: Hi, I checked this already but what is the meaning of this?
"You can only get your fee refunded if your application hasn’t been processed yet."
What is the value of fees here? The total amount i paid is 8995 INR which is the Visa application fees. Now how much will they deduct from this and how will will i get refund?

Comment: The fee means the application fee, so the amount you would be refunded would be the full amount, how long ago did you apply? And is there a reason you are looking to cancel and then reapply immediately afterwards?

Comment: Hi, the reason is i wasn't able to book the same day appointment due to some website issue so I cancelled it and submitted the new one successfully.
One more thing I needed to ask - My mother is dependent on my father as she is a house maker so do i need to have a separate cover letter for each of them or just one cover letter written by my father would work?